# Compare 2 cells in row a with 2 cells in row b

Tags: excel-formula

i wonder if you can help i am trying to highlight the row if the data in cell `A1` and `B1` match the data in `A3` and `B3`,

For Example

```
      A        B
1 -  ONE      TWO
2 -  THREE    FOUR
3 -  ONE      TWO
```

So `A1 & B1 = A3 & B3` could both rows be highlighted to show they match, any help would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `=AND(OR(A1048575=A1,A1=A3),A1<>0)` applied to =$A:$B?

*Edit*
[image: SO17400496 example]

Comment: Excel 2003, yes i think so i applied the conditional formatting to A1 + B1 (with the above formula) the ctrl+d down ?

Comment: i replaced 1048575 with 65535 this didn't work either, it highlighted A1 if C1 had the same value, many thanks for your help